# How to extract 'Odor' information from PubChem using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pubchem

I wrote the following Python code extract 'odor' information from PubChem for a particular molecule; in this case molecule nonanal (CID=31289) The webpage for this molecule is: https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/31289#section=Odor

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/31289#section=Odor'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
odor_section = soup.find('section', {'id': 'Odor'})
odor_info = odor_section.find('div', {'class': 'section-content'})

print(odor_info.text.strip())
```

I get the following error.
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
It seems that not the whole page information is extracted by BeautifulSoup.

I expect the following output:
Orange-rose odor, Floral, waxy, green

Comment: The page you're trying to scrap is generated with javascript, you either need to use an interpreter (e.g. selenium) or to access the data using NCBI's API

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that. I will try to use Selenium right now...

Comment: Standard debugging step: view the page in a browser, with JavaScript disabled. Also look at the page source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page in question makes an AJAX request to load its data. We can see this in a web browser by looking at the Network tab of the dev tools (F12 in many browsers):

[image]

[image]

That is to say, the data simply isn't there when the initial page loads - so it isn't found by BeautifulSoup.

To solve the problem:

- use Selenium, which can actually run the JavaScript code and thus populate the page with the desired data; or
- simply query the API according to the request seen when loading the page in the browser. Thus:

```
PubChem_Nonanal_CID=31289
coumpund_data_url = 'https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug_view/data/compound/{}/JSON/'
compound_info = requests.get(coumpund_data_url.format(PubChem_Nonanal_CID))

print (compund_info.json())
```

**Parsing the JSON Reply**

Parsing it proves a bit of a challenge, as it is comprised of many lists.
If the order of properties isn't guaranteed, you could opt for a solution like this:

```
for section in compund_info.json()['Record']['Section']:
    if section['TOCHeading']=="Chemical and Physical Properties":
       for sub_section in section['Section']:
           if sub_section['TOCHeading'] == 'Experimental Properties':
               for sub_sub_section in sub_section['Section']:
                   if sub_sub_section['TOCHeading']=="Odor":
                       print(sub_sub_section['Information'][0]['Value']['StringWithMarkup'][0]['String'])
                       break
```

Otherwise, follow the schema from a JSON-parsing website like [jsonformatter.com](https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser)

[image]

```
# object►Record►Section►3►Section►1►Section►2►Information►0►Value►StringWithMarkup►0►String`

odor = compund_info.json()['Record']['Section'][3]['Section'][1]['Section'][2]['Information'][0]['Value']['StringWithMarkup'][0]['String']
```